# JavaScript - table <td> click listener which makes cells editable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table on a web page with n table rows in the following format:

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left">Example</td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="center" id="dropdownTableData">
        <select id = "select" onchange="setColor(this)">
          <option value="green">pass</option>
          <option value="red">fail</option>
          <option value="blue" selected="selected">none</option>
        </select></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

I am trying to make the table behave as follows:

- when a cell is clicked on it allows the user to edit its contents
- This behaviour only happens if(!id.equals"dropDownTableData"))
- The table will retain its relative format while being edited
- if the contents of a cell are changed the cell will be highlighted yellow
- If the contents of a cell are not changed then there will be no colour change
- If a cell is edited it will have some identifier in the html it is an edited cell (for the putposes of later processing the web page).
- Whilst editing, if the user hits the return key the editing of the cell will end (it will then be highlighted yellow if changed from original).
- While editing if the user hits "shift + return" then the cell will carry over to a new line (
   / "\n").

So far I have addressed most of these by coming up with :

```
    $(function () {

      $("td").click(function (event){
        var tdObj = $(this);
        if(tdObj.attr("id") != "dropdownTableData"){

            var originalText = tdObj.text();
            var inputObj =$("<input type='text'/>");
            tdObj.html("");

            inputObj.width(tdObj.width())
            inputObj.height(tdObj.height())
            inputObj.val(originalText)
            inputObj.appendTo(tdObj)
            inputObj.trigger("focus")
            inputObj.trigger("select")
            inputObj.keyup(function(event){

                var typedText = $(this).val();

                switch(event.which){ 
                    case 13:

                        if(typedText === originalText){
                            tdObj.html(originalText);
                            tdObj.css({background: tdObj.style.background- 
                            color});

                        } else { 
                            tdObj.html(typedText);
                            tdObj.css({background: "#FEFA09"}); 
                        }
                        break; 

                    default: 
                        break;  
                }

            });

            inputObj.click(function(){
                return false;
            });
        }
      });
    });
```

This broadly achieves the behaviours im looking for however the issues with my code are :

When text is clicked on for editing it is formatted into a single line as shown in the image below, this makes it difficult for the user to read the changes they are making in the context of the rest of the cells content.

[image: onClick error]

"Shift + return" should carry over onto a new line however currently im not sure how to implement this.

Please could someone point out the areas where I've conceptually gone wrong with m approach to this too (im new to JavaScript).

Comment: `<input>` is not multiline component. Use `<textarea>` instead (edit: or `contenteditable` on a `div`).

Comment: You should also move your `click` listener on `table`. If you have a million cells, you will have million event listeners.